# Using Python Spyne (RPC) is there a way to return a native python list instead of the fancy Array or Iterable?

Tags: python, spyne

Both the Iterable and Array types seem to have a native list hidden away in them, but I find myself always doing things like:

```
myList = service.fetchRemoteList()[0][1]
```

Where `fetchRemoteList() _returns=Iterable(String)`

I don't want to have to put [0][1]  at the end of all my list function calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spyne uses wrapped arrays by default, because that's what everybody else in the XML world does.

Wrapped array:

```
<users>
    <User>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Batman</name>
    </User>
    <User>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Robin</name>
    </User>
</users>
```

Bare array:

```
<users>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Batman</name>
</users>
<users>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>Robin</name>
</users>
```

You probably can see why everybody likes wrapped arrays better now. It's a matter of convention, but surely a helpful one. Plus, it's not possible to do polymorphism with non-wrapped arrays.

Spyne also uses wrapped functions by default, because it's not possible to have multiple arguments / return values in bare mode.

Now the answers:

- Here's a wrapped array:

  ```
  Array(Unicode)
  ```

  Here's the equivalent bare array:

  ```
  Unicode(max_occurs='unbounded')
  ```

  In 2.12, you can also pass `wrapped=False` to Array to get bare arrays.
  Eg.:

  ```
  Array(Unicode, wrapped=False)
  ```
- As you discovered, you can get bare functions passing `_body_style='bare'` 
  to `@rpc`.

Some SOAP clients discover what kind of function/array it is via simple heuristics and save you the trouble of using magic indexes. Apparently suds isn't one of them.

Comment: So perhaps this is a suds issue?

Comment: Depends on who you ask :) Suds gives you the xml structure verbatim, which is a feature to some.

Answer (score -1):

This needs to *at least be documented on the website when discussing arrays*, or, more realistically, **this needs to be DEFAULT behavior** per the 'principle of least astonishment'.

There's a hard to find little variable that starts with an underscore you can use called '_body_style' and when set to the string literal 'bare' it seems to work as you would expect it to work normally:

```
@srpc(_returns=Array(String),_body_style='bare')    
def fetchRemoteList():
    yield "Item1"
    yield "Item2"
```

Comment: With the background of the XML explanation you gave, I understand why it shouldn't be default. Thanks for that, and sorry for the attitude. I do recommend it is documented on the main website in the object section, since, at least with suds, it appears to be bug since it's going in as a python object, and coming out as a wrapped object implicitly without any documentation or explanation